# Type inference and inheritance in Angular templates

Tags: angular, typescript

If I have a table component

```
TableComponent<T extends object, K extends keyof T> {
  ...

  Input()
  data!: T[];

  ContentChildren(ColumnComponent<K>)
  columns!: QueryList<ColumnComponent<K>>;

  ...
}
```

and a column component

```
ColumnComponent<K> {
  ...

  Input()
  property!: K;

  ...
}
```

and I use it like

```
<app-table [data]="someArray">
  <!-- Can I get a warning here to say some of the child components are not of type K -->
  <app-column property="validProperty" />
  <app-column property="anotherValidProperty" />
  <app-column property="invalidProperty" />
  <app-column [property]="'anotherInvalidProperty'" />
  <!-- I would like a warning here to show that some of the properties are not valid -->
<app-table>
```

Is it possible to get the column components to inherit the keys type from the parent table component so that they are strongly typed against the properties of the data array. Or maybe have the table show a warning that the some of the children are not of type K.

Here is a StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-q3pgtp?file=src%2Fmain.html

Comment: I have raised this on GitHub https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/51720

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only way you can achive this is if you'll pass the `data` of your table into each `ColumnComponent` as well, and make it also get the two generic types `<T extends object, K extends keyof T>` like in the parent `TableComponent`.
In This way, typescript will be aware that the `K` type must be a `keyof T`.

Attached is your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-f2eg7p?file=src%2Fcolumn%2Fcolumn.component.ts,src%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.ts,src%2Fmain.html) with the relevants additions, you will see that the desired warnings occurred.

**Of course,** if you got nothing to do with the `data` property in the `ColumnComponent` - consider if it worth it to add it there just for types handling. But I don't think you can achive your goal in a different way.

Comment: I really don't want to pass the data array into the config components. I really wish that the table component would complain that some of the child object are of the incorrect type.